# How to mount specific folder from the AWS S3 to ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mount

I have tried with s3fs which has option to mount complete S3 bucket but I am looking if there is any way to mount specific folder.

Comment: Its not supported.

Comment: I do no think if there an option to mount objects only. full bucket need to be mounted

Comment: @Marcin @ Deepak Gupta thank you!